# Multiple configurations for VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

At the moment I'm working on a few projects at the same time using VSCode, one in react, another in angular and some good old javascript.
The problem is that I have a few extensions installed that conflict, for example, some code snippets that are the same for React and Angular.

Is it possible to have 3 visual studio code installed on a Mac with different extensions installed?

Comment: Is it not possible to have different extension configurations for different workspaces? You can have each workspace have their own customized extension settings. For example, I have different pylint and eslint settings depending on the workspace.

Comment: you can disable an extension for a workspace, go to the extension page and use the `Disable` dropdown

Comment: try to create .setting.json files in each project. it might help

Answer (score 0):

As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61335608/multiple-configurations-for-vscode/69576299?noredirect=1#comment135031494_69576299) by Shannon, VSCode now supports profiles, that does this natively. You can use **File > Preferences > Profiles > Create Profile**. See [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles) for further details.

Original answer:

There are two options for such setup:

1. Portable installation - unzip VSCode in a folder and create a subfolder there called `data`. This will trigger the portable mode and all settings will be stored in that `data` folder. The downside is that you'll have to manually update every portable folder whenever new version comes out. More info [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable).
2. Custom config paths - create a shortcut for your VSCode installation, and add those parameters:
   `--user-data-dir <some-path> --extensions-dir <some-path>`
   You can put them wherever and have as much shortcuts as you want, they even run in parallel. Best part is once you update the installation, all the configs are upgraded too. More info [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_advanced-cli-options).

Both modes are incompatible, so you have to choose one.

Comment: good news is --user-data-dir --extensions-dir is no longer needed since Settings Sync and Profiles are now part of VS Code